# Using reflection to create an object represented by the contents of a "Type" object

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am using reflection to find a type by a string like this...

```
Type currentType = Type.GetType(typeName);
```

I then am able to get a list of properties for that type like this...

```
var props = currentType.GetProperties();
```

How do I instantiate a new object of this type and then start assigning values to the properties of that object based on the list of properties in the props list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the values you already have...

```
var created = Activator.CreateInstance(currentType);

foreach(var prop in props)
{
    prop.SetValue(created, YOUR_PROPERTY_VALUE, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate the `currentType` with:

```
var newInst = Activator.CreateInstance(currentType);
```

and assign property values with:

```
propInfo.SetValue(newInst, propValue, BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, null, null);
```

Where `propInfo` is the `PropertyInfo` instance from your `props` and `propValue` is the object you want to assign to the property.

EDIT:

I always lean towards using the more verbose `SetValue` overload because I've had problems with the short one in the past, but `propInfo.SetValue(newInst, propValue, null);` might work as well.